Ubuntu 24.04 no longer notifies of updates
Just noticed this the other day.
Prior versions of Ubuntu notified if there was updates both OS and Apps were available.
The other Day I noticed a very small warning (triangle) in top right of desktop stating the update notification was outdated so I ran my software updater and there was a huge update available which I've installed.
Is there a problem with update notifications on latest Ubuntu Desktop ?
Hit:1 ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease 
Get:2 ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB] Hit:3 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease 
Hit:4 ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease Fetched 126 kB in 1s (141 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree... 
Done Reading state information... 
Done 5 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Hit:1 ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease 
Get:2 ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB] Hit:3 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease 
Hit:4 ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease Fetched 126 kB in 1s (141 kB/s) Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree... 
Done Reading state information... 
Done 5 packages can be upgraded. 
Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.


Please post the output of the command sudo apt update

Hit:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Get:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB]
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Fetched 126 kB in 1s (141 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
5 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

In future please edit the post and paste these. It looks good. Just update using GUI. In the update settings you can set how often the computer will check for upgrades
